# Bad argument in iptables NAT command

Tags: 20.04, iptables, nat

I am trying to do a DNAT rule in iptables if the packet with source address 192.168.86.212 and destination address 192.168.86.212 then change the destination address to 172.217.5.100.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING   -s 192.168.86.213/32 -d 192.168.96.212/32 -j DNAT -to-destination 172.217.5.100
```

But I got this error message:

```
Bad argument `172.217.5.100'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

I am very new to Ubuntu, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I suspect `-to-destination` (single dash) should be `--to-destination` (double dash)

Comment: @steeldriver you are right!! no error prompt anymore. Sorry about the stupid question:(

Comment: No problem - sometimes these things just need a second pair of eyes, especially when the error message is not particularly helpful

Comment: @steeldriver how do I give you the reputation or the best answer?

Comment: I have posted a brief answer below if you should decide to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man iptables-extensions`, the `DNAT` target option is `--to-destination` (with two dashes) rather than `-to-destination`:

```
   DNAT
       This  target is only valid in the nat table, in the PREROUTING and OUT‐
       PUT chains, and user-defined chains which are only  called  from  those
       chains.  It specifies that the destination address of the packet should
       be modified (and all future packets in this  connection  will  also  be
       mangled),  and rules should cease being examined.  It takes the follow‐
       ing options:

       --to-destination [ipaddr[-ipaddr]][:port[-port]]
```

It's not obvious why the error message flags the `ipaddr` argument rather than the option itself.

Comment: Thank you so much!